# Detener la lectura de codigos de barra mientras un alertDialog siga activo

Tags: android

El problema es el siguiente:
Al estar escaneando códigos de barras con un equipo Zebra TC-25
si la app detecta un código de barras que no se encuentra en la base proporcionada, genera un alertDialog para evitar que el usuario siga escaneando más códigos hasta que oprima el botón "entiendo"

Sin embargo, esto no ocurre, hay alguna manera de poder realizar esta acción?

Algo de código:

```java
//METODO PARA CONSULTAR BC CONTRA LA BD Y REGISTRARLOS EN LA BD
    private void ValidaryRegistrarBarcode(){
        if (ConsultarBarcode())
        {
            arrayList_InventarioCaptuado_ENT.add(0,new InventarioCapturado_Entidad(RegistrarBarcode(), txtCB.getText().toString().replace("nn", "")));
            vcontador++;
            lblContador.setText(Integer.toString(vcontador)); //se sube el contador de la lista

            MostrarCodigosdeBarraCapturados();
        }else{
            //Reproduce un sonido de alerta cuando no encuentra el BC en la BD
            MediaPlayer mediaplayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.raw.alerta);
            mediaplayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    mediaPlayer.reset();
                    mediaPlayer.release();
                }
            });
            mediaplayer.start();

            // Alerta de BARCODE NO ENCONTRADO
            AlertDialog.Builder alerta = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            alerta.setMessage("No se encontro el codigo de barras, para continuar e intentar de nuevo presione ENTENDIDO")
                    .setPositiveButton("   Entendido   ", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            //

                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog titulo = alerta.create();
            titulo.setTitle("¡ALERTA!");
            titulo.show();
        }
        txtCB.getText().clear();
    }
```

Edit:
estoy tomando el siguiente frente:
Cree una nueva actividad para poder enviar el metodo despues del `else`
para que quede justo como `errorCaptura()`

Sin embargo mi app se cierra al llegar a ese punto del metodo

```java
    private void errorCaptura() {
        Intent errorCaptura = new Intent (getActivity(), com.Vistas.errorCaptura.class);
        startActivity(errorCaptura);
    }
```

Claro de vuelta estoy enviando de regreso al usuario de nuevo a la pantalla de captura una vez que pase de esa porción

capturaError:

```java
public class errorCaptura extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.error_captura);

    }

    public void Entendido(View view) {
        Intent capturaFragment = new Intent(this, com.Vistas.capturaFragment.class);
        startActivity(capturaFragment);
    }
}
```

ConsultarBarcode:

```java
//METODO para Verificar si el BC esta en la base de la Tienda
    private boolean ConsultarBarcode() { //PARA CONSULTAR SI EL CB ES PARTE DE LOS CODIGOS DE BARRA DE LA BD
        boolean correcto = false;

        SQLiteDatabase db = conn.getWritableDatabase();

        try {

            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select barcodeFijo from invtFijo Where barcodeFijo = " + txtCB.getText().toString() , null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            if (cursor.getCount()>0){
                cursor.close();
                return true;
            }
            else{
                cursor.close();
                return false;
            }

        }catch (Exception e){
            //Mensaje de error para el barcode
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"ERROR METODO -CONSULTAR-" + " "+ e.getMessage().toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        db.close();
        return correcto;
    }
```

Comment: Consulta, ¿QUé se supone que hay en ConsultarBarCode? Parece una función o método que retorna o true o false.

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo añadi la porcion que pides es una seccion que consulta en base si el bc es parte o no de los bc que vienen dentro de la bd de sqlite de la app

Comment: A mi se me hace que tu error está en esa porción que agregaste porque según yo siempre te devuelve `false`. Creas una variable `boolean correcto = false` y al terminar tu función o método le dices `return correcto` viendo tu `if` jamás le asignas `true` a `correcto` por lo que siempre saldrá `false`

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo Muchas gracias por mencionarlo voy a probar, también otra opción que estaba pensando es en evitar usar un alertDialog y llamar mejor a otra pantalla para que muestre la alerta al usuario y así evitar la ejecución de código dentro de esa clase

Comment: También, pero mientras no corrijas ese error del `ConsultarBarCode` siempre obtendrás el error